# create temp file name in php

Tags: php, jquery

For saving a document/image in PHP, I am using `move_uploaded_file($tmp, "location")`.

I'm getting the value of the document/image while the file is changing, so I got the file name, but I can't create `tmp_name`, because I'm getting `name` in the following way:

**HTML:**

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" id="upload" onChange="change(this.value)" />
    <input type="submit" name="chk" value="Submit" />
    <div id="div"></div>
</form>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
<script src="js/jquery1.js"></script>
<script>
function change(val){
    $.ajax({
        url:"filecheck.php?id=" + val,
        success:function(res){
            alert(res);
        }
    });
}
```

**PHP:** filecheck.php

```
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("newdatabase");

if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
    $name=$_GET['id'];
    $tmp=$_GET['id']['tmp_name']; //here i need temp file name
    move_uploaded_file($tmp, "C:/xampp/htdocs/jerome/project/newimage/".$name); 
    echo $name;
}
```

If I get the filename by `$_FILES['file']['name']`, it means I can get `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']`, but I can't get by this way. Can you please give me a suggestion on how to get `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']`?

Comment: You're referencing `$_GET` and not `$_FILES`..... That will be your issue.

Comment: yes i am getting file name while onchange.. see the script

Comment: Does not matter, tmp name will never be the original filename..
U have to use the `$_FILES` array for this (http://www.sanwebe.com/2012/06/ajax-file-upload-with-php-and-jquery)

Comment: calling a function on `onChange` event doesn't mean that you are uploading a file. So `$_FILES` will be empty at that time. Certainly you are doing it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you're trying to access the file from the `$_GET` superglobal instead of the `$_FILES` superglobal where it would be held.

A simple check with the below code would show you the file data:

```
print_r($_FILES);
```

There is also an issue with your ajax.

```
function change(val){
    $.ajax({
        url:"filecheck.php?id=" + val,
        type: "post",
        data: $('#yourformid').serialize()
        success:function(res){
            alert(res);
        }
    });
}
```

I can see you're trying to do an instant upload via ajax. The way you are doing it now is bad.

You should look at the following tutorials to grasp an understanding of how it should be done:

- [Upload via php/ajax](http://www.sanwebe.com/2012/05/ajax-image-upload-and-resize-with-jquery-and-php)
- [Upload file in PHP via ajax](http://devzone.co.in/upload-file-php-using-jquery-ajax/)
- [Google Search for "php/ajax file upload"](https://www.google.com.au/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=php%2Fajax%20file%20upload)

Otherwise you'd just check like this:

```
if(!empty($_FILES)) {

    $name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $tmp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
}
```

---

**NOTE**

Look at [**`code-jaffs comment`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24881624/create-temp-file-name-in-php/24881892#comment38647792_24881624) that verifies my point above stating that your files won't upload the way you are currently doing this.

Comment: U got a copy/paste error in the last link (google one)

Comment: @Darren, Thanks. Will try another way

Comment: i am using this plugin get what i want http://www.a2zwebhelp.com/jquery-php-file-upload..

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with `$tmp=$_GET['id']['tmp_name'];`..This should be changed to `$tmp=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];` as code-jaff says..

The usage of get can be found here  http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Comment: i can only get file name by GET, can not get by FILES[].. because it's in another page, Is  there any way create tmp_name by GET?

Comment: @user3822048 see $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']; will contain the temporary file name of the file on the server. This is just a placeholder on your server until you process the file.